# Does ReaderWriterLockSlim have a finalizer?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.dispose(v=vs.100).aspx) states that if the method `Dispose` is not called, then any resources will not be released until GC calls the finalizer of the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` object.

However, the class `ReaderWriterLockSlim` doesn't appear to contain a finalizer (using .NET Reflector), why not? Perhabs do they mean a GC-hosted 'finalizing' process instead of a `Finalize` method?

footnote; I am aware that I should always dispose disposable objects.

Comment: Copy/paste bug in the MSDN article, not uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReaderWriterLockSlim` doesn't directly own any unmanaged resources, so it doesn't need a finalizer.

Its [`Dispose` method (source)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/system/threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim/ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs,1189) simply disposes other managed resources.

If you don't dispose it, its managed resources will run [their finalizers](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/safehandle.cs,199) and release the underlying handles.

Comment: Ok so I assume that the documentation is not as accurate as I'd like.